# Arranging PCI-e cards to maximize performance in machine

Tags: audio, performance, graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express

I just put a new machine together using an ASUS Republic of Gamers Rampage 4 Extreme motherboard. The machine has 2 nVidia GTX 660s, an Adaptec SAS/SATA 6G controller and a Creative Sound Blaster Z sound card.

Originally I just popped parts into the first available slots in the machine and that was that. But after reading a little more into my board I can accross this in the specs.

Expansion Slots

- 4 x PCIe 3.0/2.0 x16 (x16 or dual x16 or x16/x8/x16 or x16/x8/x8/x8,
  red) *1
- 1 x PCIe 3.0/2.0 x16 (x8 mode, gray) *1
- 1 x PCIe 2.0 x1

As is stands right now I have the lot of everything plugged into the red slots. So if this reduces the effective bandwidth of my bus(es) to x8 instead of x16?

The SAS controller needs x8 slot, the GPUs need x16s and the sound card needs a x1. Would there be any advantage to re organizing the cards into respective busses?

Comment: Any changes wouldn't make a difference

Comment: The GTX 660 is not fast enough to make any significant difference.  It would take a lot of hard drives attached to the Adaptec controller to make a difference.  How many hard drives are attached?

Comment: I only have 4 drives. The controller maxes out at 8. I kinda see where this is going.